# PHP. Get data send with <form action="url.php?var=DATA"></form>

Tags: php

How to get a value of the `$_GET`?

E.G

How to get number `14` from `action="doSomething.php?OrderNumber=14"`

I know how to check if the `orderNumber === "14"`, but I need to get this value and use it somewhere else.

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: What about `$_GET['OrderNumber']`?

Comment: @fabio - $var = $_GET['orderNumber'] ? As simple as that?

Comment: @NewUser are you saying you are developing SOAP connections with ``$_POST`` data and you can't handle ``$_GET`` data ? That's weird ...

Comment: You don't even need to assign it to another var, just use $_GET['orderNumber']. Just keep in mind to escape it when you need because is untrusted user input and it could lead to XSS or sql injection.

Comment: @Mihai Iorga - it it all learning process.. Working on my first CRM and sometimes I'm missing basics.

Comment: @NewUser: The basics are well explained in the PHP Manual, for example: [Variables From External Sources](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$_GET['OrderNumber']` or `$_REQUEST['OrderNumber']`

Comment: What the difference between those two?

Comment: `$_REQUEST` is a merge of `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE`: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: @PaulPRO - So basically I can use `$_REQUEST` to get data from any of above?

Comment: What is the advantage of using `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: @NewUser it works when you don't know whether the data is coming from a POST or a GET request. Other than that not much.

Comment: Sometimes you don't know what methods is used GET or POST. In this case it's useful.

Answer (score 2):

The same as you would normally retrieve a GET variable:

```
$orderNumber = $_GET['orderNumber']; //Stores 14
```

You can find more information about [`$_GET` here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Comment: Done, I assume that's what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

If you dump `$_GET` using `print_r` for instance, you will notice that it is actually an key/value array. So if you want to get OrderNumber, you just have to use:

```
<?php
$order = (int)$_GET['OrderNumber']; # to unsure ordernumber is a number
// use $order anywhere you want
save($order); // for instance
```

in the file doSomething.php.

Comment: int is setting jsut the type of the data?

Comment: This will result in a fatal error, because `int` is not a function. Probably you meant `$order = (int) $_GET['OrderNumber'];`

Answer (score 0):

$_GET['var'] should be populated in url.php after form is submitted, $_GET['OrderNumber'] should be populated in doSomething.php after form is submitted, if this is not the answer, please elaborate.